# how to print orderbook horizontal?

Tags: c#

I don't know better place to ask, I am sorry if this is not pure C# question.

I need to analyze tick data of stock exchange orderbook. Every time update in orderbook occurs (order is added or deleted or moved or executed) I need to "checkpoint" new state and to compare it with previous state. So far I just print data to text file and it looks like that:

```
5/31/2012 6:06:58 AM:313

3466 1
3464 40
3460 10
3456.9 1
3456 1
3454 1
3448 760
3446 6
3445 3
3444.8 7
3444.5 4
3430.4 6
3420 400
3400 400
3399.9 5
3399.8 2
3396 12
3393.9 1
3390 99
3389.9 14

3387.2 17
3383.7 2
3383.6 2
3376.3 2
3361.1 9
3361 25
3360.8 3
3360.7 3
3360 2
3358 1
3357 3
3356.3 2
3351.1 60
3351 10
3350.6 20
3342.2 3
3342 15
3331.2 180
3331.1 63
3318 3

5/31/2012 6:06:58 AM:359

3466 1
3464 40
3460 10
3456.9 1
3456 1
3454 1
3448 760
3446 6
3445 3
3444.8 7
3444.5 4
3430.4 6
3420 400
3400 400
3399.9 5
3399.8 2
3396 12
3393.9 1
3390 99
3389.9 14

3387.2 17
3383.7 2
3383.6 2
3376.3 2
3361.5 9
3361.4 15
3361.2 9
3361.1 3
3360.8 3
3360.7 3
3360 2
3358 1
3356.3 2
3351.2 11
3351.1 60
3350.6 20
3342.2 3
3342 15
3331.2 180
3331.1 63
```

But I want to look it something like that:

```
6:06:58 AM:313          6:06:58 AM:359

3466    1               3466    1
3464    40              3464    40
3460    10              3460    10
3456.9  1               3456.9  1
3456    1               3456    1
3454    1               3454    1
3448    760             3448    760
3446    6               3446    6
3445    3               3445    3
3444.8  7               3444.8  7
3444.5  4               3444.5  4
3430.4  6               3430.4  6
3420    400             3420    400
3400    400             3400    400
3399.9  5               3399.9  5
3399.8  2               3399.8  2
3396    12              3396    12
3393.9  1               3393.9  1
3390    99              3390    99
3389.9  14              3389.9  14

3387.2  17              3387.2  17
3383.7  2               3383.7  2
3383.6  2               3383.6  2
3376.3  2               3376.3  2
                 added  3361.5  9
                 added  3361.4  15
3361.1  9               3361.2  9       
                 added  3361.1  3
3361    25     deleted
3360.8  3               3360.8  3
3360.7  3               3360.7  3
3360    2               3360    2
3358    1               3358    1
3357    3      deleted
3356.3  2               3356.3  2
                 added  3351.2  11
3351.1  60              3351.1  60
3351    10     deleted
3350.6  20              3350.6  20
3342.2  3               3342.2  3
3342    15              3342    15
3331.2  180             3331.2  180
3331.1  63              3331.1  63
```

- I have up to 1000 checkpoints
- I need to print them all in one line so I can compare easily
- Would it be a problem for a text file to contain lines with length up to 100 000 ?
- How to implement what I want to implement?
- If you have better suggestion how I can compare a lot of "snapshots" they are welcome! Probably I can use something different, not a text file?

Comment: _"If you have better suggestion how ..."_ What about a database?

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok i can write to database, but how will I compare each checkpoint to the next one? I prefer to avoid database as I want simplest solution. I don't want to install database just for that. It's "debug purpose" feature.

Comment: @ThinkingSites I just tried to write to text file and that's it.

Comment: If really feels like you're getting us to do your coding for you, but I'll give you the benefit of the doubt.  It's easily possible to have 1000 data points, and you can have text files as large as you want.  As for implementation, post what code you have for parsing and we can go from there.  I have my ideas of how to solve this, but it's a fair amount of coding to get it right.  I'll post instructions instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some instructions will conceptualize it for you:

1. loop through every line of your file
2. check each entry to see if it's a date, if so, create a new instance of some data object
3. keep parsing until you reach another date,
4. save your data objects in a list of data object
5. repeat steps 1 through 5 until you're done with the file
6. when you're ready to print, write the a single from each data object at a time, so you write all dates first, then the all first items in your data objects' dictionary, and so forth until you're done

Comment: all structures are already in memory so i don't need to parse anything. likely I just should write some straightforward algorithm...